# Not sure if I should use celery

Tags: django, celery, django-celery

I have never used celery before and I'm also a django newbie so I'm not sure if I should use celery in my project.

**Brief description of my project:**

There is an API for sending (via SSH) jobs to scientific computation clusters. The API is an abstraction to the different scientific job queue vendors out there. http://saga-project.github.io/saga-python/
My project is basically about doing a web GUI for this API with django.

So, my concern is that, if I use celery, I would have a queue in the local web server and another one in each of the remote clusters. I'm afraid this might complicate the implementation needlessly.

The API is still in development and some of the features aren't fully finished. There is a function for checking the state of the remote job execution (running, finished, etc.) but the callback support for state changes is not ready. Here is where I think celery might be appropriate. I would have one or several periodic task(s) monitoring the job states.

Any advice on how to proceed please? No celery at all? celery for everything? celery just for the job states?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use celery for similar purpose and it works well. Basically I have one node running celery workers that manage the entire cluster. These workers generate input data for the cluster nodes, assign tasks, process the results for reporting or generating dependent tasks.

Each cluster node is running a very small python server which takes a db id of it's assigned job. It then calls into the main (http) server to request the data it needs and finally posts the data back when complete. In my case, the individual nodes don't need to message each other and run time of each task is very long (hours). This makes the delays introduced by central management and polling insignificant.

It would be possible to run a celery worker on each node taking tasks directly from the message queue. That approach is appealing. However, I have complex dependencies that are easier to work out from a centralized control. Also, I sometimes need to segment the cluster and centralized control makes this possible to do on the fly.

Celery isn't good at managing priorities or recovering lost tasks (more reasons for central control).

Thanks for calling my attention to SAGA. I'm looking at it now to see if it's useful to me.

Answer (score 1):

Celery is useful for execution of tasks which are too expensive to be executed in the handler of HTTP request (i.e. Django view). Consider making an HTTP request from Django view to some remote web server and think about latencies, possible timeouts, time for data transfer, etc. It also makes sense to queue computation intensive tasks taking much time for background execution with Celery.

We can only guess what web GUI for API should do. However Celery fits very well for queuing requests to scientific computation clusters. It also allows to track the state of  background task and their results.

I do not understand your concern about having many queues on different servers. You can have Django, Celery broker (implementing queues for tasks) and worker processes (consuming  queues and executing Celery tasks) all on the same server.

Comment: hi, thanks for answering. The queues in the clusters are not celery queues. They are independent implementations and the API connects via SSH and manages these queues from the command line. My worker processes wouldn't really do any real job, they would actually manage the 'real' (remote in the clusters) job queues.

Comment: I think I will also need a mechanism for caching the ssh connections. Just seem the example [here](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#instantiation) and it does seem very appropriate indeed.